# Multiple Monitor Software for Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors

I've switched over to Windows 7 full time but really miss using Ultramon, is there any other   similar software out there that works on Windows 7?

Comment: The latest version of UltraMon works perfectly fine with Windows 7...

Answer (score 14):

[DisplayFusion](http://www.binaryfortress.com/displayfusion/) works with Windows 7.

[image]

Features list from its website:

- Advanced Multi-Monitor Taskbar support
- Use a different desktop wallpaper image on each monitor
- Use a desktop wallpaper image that spans all monitors
- Randomly change your desktop wallpaper using local images or images from Flickr
- Drag or middle-click the taskbar of maximized windows to move them to other screens
- Auto-snap windows to the edge of your monitor
- Integrated Flickr.com image search & download
- Integrated Vladstudio.com image search & download
- Manage application windows with fully customizable hotkeys:

Comment: Didn't know about this, just installed on my Win7 x32 desktop. Works great!

Comment: +1: I use this too.. only slight irritation is that the applications can't _only_ appear on the taskbar on a particular monitor :-(

Comment: @Jon new version (2009-05-31) can show apps only on appropriate monitor. 

DF toolbar is now usable, but still does not work exactly like W7 taskbar. Two huge missing features are pining and task lists. Another useful one would be aero-preview / show desktop zone in the right corner.

Comment: "Drag or middle-click the taskbar of maximized windows to move them to other screens" and "Auto-snap windows to the edge of your monitor" are built into Windows 7.

Answer (score 9):

With this list of shortcuts, maybe just maybe we don't need multi-monitor software.

[Windows 7 Keyboard Shortcuts](http://blogs.msdn.com/mohamedg/archive/2009/03/15/new-keyboard-shortcuts-in-windows-7-beta.aspx)

- <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> Aero desktop peek, just like that small rectangle at the right bottom corner next to the time display.
- <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Left Arrow</kbd> toggle docking to half the screen starting by the left half
- <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Right Arrow</kbd> toggle docking to half the screen starting by the right half
- <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Left Arrow</kbd> move the window one monitor left in a multi-monitor display
- <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Right Arrow</kbd> move the window one monitor right in a multi-monitor display
- <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Up Arrow</kbd> maximize
- <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Down Arrow</kbd> minimize
- <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Home</kbd> minimize/maximize all inactive windows
- <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> show presentation mode projector options
- <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> show desktop gadgets
- <kbd>Win</kbd> + Any number (1, 2, 3, .., 0) open the corresponding taskbar pinned program
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + Click a pinned taskbar icon to cycle through the program’s open windows (e.g. IE)
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + Click a pinned taskbar icon to run a new instance of the program as administrator
- <kbd>Shift</kbd> + Click a pinned taskbar icon to run a new instance of the program

Comment: Nice...I didn't know about the Win + Shift + Left/Right - no need for any third party guff running!!

Answer (score 2):

[image]

[Display Fusion](http://www.binaryfortress.com/displayfusion/) works fine with Windows 7, in particular [version 3.0.6](http://www.binaryfortress.com/displayfusion/changelog/) (released 2009-06-01).

They added glass and support for showing the app only on the monitor the windows is on (two key features to be usable on Windows 7).

Several Windows 7 features are still missing:

- Jump Lists. This is the most obvious one.
- Pinning the window (so there is a shortcut when app is closed)
- Button combining -- DF does not support "Always combine, hide labels" mode (default in Windows 7), but looks OK with no combining.
- Window previews -- not Windows 7 style, no close button, cannot show multiple apps / IE tabs at once.
- Color is a off -- native Windows 7 toolbar seems darker, active window is highlighted differently. On mouse over, Windows 7 highlights in different colors, DF does not.

This is not meant to be picky - Display Fusion works well and is remarkably polished, but more remains to be done for full Windows 7 support. Pro version (required to support multiple taskbars) is $20, and well worth the price.

Other apps to watch (no Windows 7 support now, but probably coming up) are:

- [UltraMon](http://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/) $40
- [MultiMon](http://www.mediachance.com/free/multimon.htm) free for basic version, $30 for advanced

Answer (score 1):

I found this on - jens-schaller.de

> Disabling the window buttons in the registry will allow you to use UltraMon, to do this run regedit.exe, go to 'HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Realtime Soft\UltraMon\\Window Buttons', then change the value of 'Maximize to Desktop Button' and 'Move Window Button' from one to zero.

Maybe this will get your current setup, up and running. (Preferable as you dont have to buy a new package :) )

Answer (score 1):

See [the Comparison table of multi-monitor software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_multi-monitor_software) on Wiki to select necessary software for your need.

Comment: There is no such Wiki

Answer (score 1):

Dexpot is a great combination of a bunch of programs and offers virtual desktops, and is free.

Comment: The op was asking about multiple monitor control programs, not virtual desktops. :)

Comment: Dexpot does this as a primary function and also supports virtual desktops. :)

Comment: Nice!  Maybe I'll take another look at it.  Perhaps clarify that it supports the requested functions++ in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I’m surprised nobody mentioned [PowerStrip](http://downloads.guru3d.com/PowerStrip-3.75-download-169.html). I have always seen it recommended in multi-monitor discussions for years.