# Can't Move Windows to 2nd Monitor without Left Mouse and Cntl Key

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors

I have 2 monitors (different sizes and resolutions) setup with the "Extended" monitor Win7
setup.

## Problem 1

I can not "move" a window from my Primary Monitor (larger and higher resolution on right side in front of me) to my Secondary 2nd monitor (smaller and lower resolution) with just selecting the title bar with the left mouse button and dragging it to the left.  Windows 7 "snaps" it back to the right Primary Monitor when the window is physically in the 2nd window area as I'm holding the left mouse button.  I can prevent this problem - by holding down the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> Key with the Left Mouse button, but this is extremely annoying to me.

## Problem 2

I typically "lose" focus if I try typing input on the 2nd monitor. Typing is erratic with regard to keystroke accuracy from my keyboard translated into input on the 2nd screen.  No problem with typing input on the primary left monitor.

I find this extremely annoying and turning off the "snap" feature via the Control panel does NOT work for me.  Win7 stubbornly refuses to move my selected window to my 2nd monitor without me "forcing" Win7 to do this with the Cntrl Key.

I have tried various solutions including changing the resolutions of one or both of my monitors and sometimes "temporarily helps" but reverts back to the problem.  Also if I swap the logical (not physical) layout so that I tell Win7 the monitors are setup in a reserved situation (Large monitor on the left, and small on the right) - this also sometimes helps for awhile - but is very awkward to work with "backwards".  But all of these temporary solutions stop working.  The only solution that consistently works for "moving" the screens is to hold the Cntrl Key down as I'm moving window with the left mouse selected on the title bar.  Even that however, doesn't prevent the loss of typing focus for me on the 2nd monitor - while at the same time the typing on the 1st monitor is fine.

I have also tried the suggested shortcut - Windows Key + Shift, Left arrow Key (pressed together)  or the same combo with The Right arrow Key - this doesn't move my windows at all (right or left).  BTW - Win Key with "+" does engage the magnifier and maximizes my screen onto both monitors and I can restore the window with Win "-" fine.

Any help on moving my window screens from my Primary Monitor to my Secondary monitor without having to press the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key while holding down my left mouse button with be appreciated.  Also any help on gaining typing "focus" into my 2nd screen with be helpful too.

Comment: I find it slightly intriguing that you have a problem with keystroke input on the second monitor. It seems to indicate that your problem is a bit more serious than a simple software issue. What is the specification of your machine?

Comment: This sounds so far from the default behavior, I have to assume you're using some kind of *desktop enhancement software*.

Comment: I am using PowerPro - and will try the problem without it.

Comment: @JohnC: This [PowerPro](http://powerpro.cresadu.com/)?

Comment: Can't see your PowerPro link ref (firewalled here right now) - but it's PowerPro 4.7.0.0.  I use it for the multiple desktop features - which I've loved for years.  Also use it for keystroke macros.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg - I could not agree more with this sentiment.  I'm scratching my head reading this, *and half my job is supporting users with multi-monitor configuration issues*.  I think this MUST be some software mucking about.

Comment: @JohnC: The website says there is a 4.9 available. But the software seems to be very old and doesn't look well maintained. It might be disappointing to hear, but maybe you should look for alternative software that can provide you the equal service.

Comment: ok- basic move problem disappears when I shutdown PowerPro.  So that answer's that question.  I would guess typing focus will be restored as well.  Now I need to find a better replacement for PowerPro - that will let me use multiple desktops and also Keystroke macros...... thanks for your help!!  R / - John :))

Comment: Oliver - great reply and I will start looking for a better (and newer) replacement supported by Win7.... any suggestions for multiple desktops and also Key macros in the same tool ?  - thanks very much!  - John :)

Comment: @JohnC: I took the liberty of summarizing the comments in an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You noted in the comments that you're using [PowerPro](http://powerpro.cresadu.com/). I am certain this is the cause of your troubles (and you confirmed this through your comments).

The PowerPro website notes that there is a version 4.9 [available](http://powerpro.cresadu.com/xdownload.shtml). This could possibly help with your issues. It may be worth a try.

In my personal opinion, the website of PowerPro does not look like it (or the software itself) is still well maintained. I would strongly advise you to look into alternative software.

### Alternatives

> Related: [Multiple Monitor Software for Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/250103/multiple-monitor-software-for-windows-7)

Without knowing exactly what PowerPro provides to you, possibly a software like [UltraMon](http://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/) (UltraMon costs US$39.95) is what you need.

Besides 3rd-party software. You already noted that you know about hotkeys in Windows 7 like <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Left Arrow</kbd>. In my opinion, a lot of valuable features regarding multi-monitor support were added in Windows 7 (like these hotkeys).

Comment: Yes - seems to be the source of both of my problems.  I think I also have a keyboard issue with a non-standard keyboard - that would answer the Cntrl Shift issue (but will discover that later).... thank-you very much for your expert help.  Quickly zeroed in on my problem - experience helps.... thanks again - John

Comment: I have switched over to Virtual Desktop Manager called [Dexpot](http://www.dexpot.de) V1.5.17 (freeware and portable) and appears to me (so far) to behave very well with multiple monitors and Win7.  It suites my needs minus keystroke macros that PowerPro had.  I am looking at [AutoHotKey](http://portableapps.com/node/26034) portable for that.  Thanks - John